# Example of $4\times 4$ real Normal matrix which is neither hermitian nor unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I want to find an example of a real Normal $4\times 4$ matrix which is neither hermitian nor unitary. And thank you for your help.

Comment: Take the identity matrix $I$, then look at $\alpha I$, where $\alpha\in\mathbb C$ with $\text{Im}(\alpha)\neq0$ (so it's not self-adjoint) and $|\alpha|\neq1$ (so it's not unitary).

Comment: it Can be an example but I prefer that the coefficient of the matrix are real

Comment: Fine then take any unitary $U$ which is not self-adjoint, and look at $\alpha U$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ and $|\alpha|\neq1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\-2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$